# IP address from web history

Tags: google-account, ip-address

The web history help page (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/54068?hl=en&ref_topic=14148) states that along with search results it collects the IP address data for each search, i.e., an indication of where the search originated.

However, this information is not displayed in the web history online.

How can I get IP address data from my web history?

Comment: For what it's worth, every web server you visit (or get assets from) records and logs your IP address.

Comment: There's a ton of information in Google's [My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/) tool. If you dig down into the details of a search item, it won't show the IP address, but it _will_ show the location of where it thinks the search originated from.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the IP address data was meant to be displayable. It might only facilitate Google in providing better search results and resolving account security issues. It might be possible that the [takeout data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190) contains such information, I cannot confirm this at the moment.

Meanwhile the [Activity Information](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en) tab of Gmail does display IP address of locations where you where logged in.